# parsing success callbacks from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have a backbone object that I'm calling save on.  How do I know what comes back in the ajax call.  Looking at the code for the project I got put on, I see some people just have a generic

```
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
```

Then other times, I see:

```
success: function (library, response) {
console.log(library);
console.log(response)
```

I'm confused on how you would know you would have I presume a library or response object, vs a general data.  When I look at the second example, I am looking at the output of

```
console.log(response);
```

and I see response has three attributes:

```
Notifications
Response
ResponseStatus
```

Response itself looks like `Object {Id="12345", href="the/href", Name="asdf"}`

So it looks like a Javascript object to me, but then when I try to do

```
console.log(response.Name);
```

I always get undefined even though I can see the value.

So I'm trying to understand how the callback in an ajax calls.  Like when you can use an actual library object, response object, vs a data object, and how I can go about parsing the results properly.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you want: `console.log(response.Response.Name);`?

Comment: Wpdoherty926 Doh!  Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either

```
$.ajax({
   dataType : 'json',
   ..
})
```

or

```
$.ajax({
   ..
   success : function(data) {
      var result = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Then I think you will be good